# how to parse php and html

Tags: php, html, wordpress, parsing

I have a wordpress page that I'd like to put a mad lib on. I have created the html file as well as the php file. http://www.melissaannford.com/dasfrozun/fu/ The html works great in the page, but the php it's linked to appears on a seperate page. To solve this, one of my friends suggested parsing the two files so that the php reads the entered html in the same file.  I looked up the different "How to parse html with php" questions on here, and saw that it was a common question, but none of them helped much.

I don't need someone to do thenter code here`e work for me, I'm just looking for guidance on how to even begin doing this. Do I use "echo insert_html_here" or what?

The PHP is:

```
<?
print <<<HERE
<h3>
Little Boy $color, come taste your $flavor! popsicle<br>
Lick it up before it $adjective!<br>
Once it's gone, do not fret! Das  Frozun never runs out<br>
You can enjoy a popsicle while $action.
</h3>
HERE;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<h3>Fill in the blanks below, and I'll tell
you a story</h3>
<form action="../story.php" method="post">
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Color:</th>
<th><input type="text" name="color" value="" /></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Favorite Flavor</th>
<th><input type="text" name="flavor" value="" /></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Adjective</th>
<th><input type="text" name="adjective" value="" /></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>An action</th>
<th>
<select name="action">
<option value="walking">walking</option>
<option value="playing">playing</option>
<option value="watching tv">watching tv</option>
<option value="doing homework">doing homework</option>
</select>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><center>
<input type="submit" value="tell me the story" /></center></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

I want the PHP code to take the HTML and insert it, like it already does on the other page, but on the exact same page.

Comment: Please provide some more info on what do you need to achieve. Give some example, maybe even code example to start with.

Comment: All right, I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a HTML preprocessing language. Every PHP file can contain HTML outside of the `<?php ?>` tags. So, let's say you have a file called `test.php`:

```
This is HTML and will be rendered as such
<?php
echo 'Hello World from PHP';
$a = 12;
// etc
?>
This is HTML again
```

If you want to include HTML from some other file, you can use the `include()` function. Alternatively, you may be interested in templating libraries like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Comment: I'm attempting to combine the HTML from the one file, into the same file as the php. I have included the file link to the php in the html, but then it redirects the user to another page.

Comment: What do you mean by the file link to the php in the html? HTML files can't process PHP - only the other way around.

Comment: In my HTML I have: <form action="../story.php" method="post"> This sends the action of the form to my php file. I'd like that php file to become part of the HTML file, though, so that both are merged into one.

Comment: So basically you want to display a PHP page based on something entered on the HTML page. My tip: Move the HTML to the PHP and display either the form, or the result, based on whether any data was submitted yet (e.g. `isset($_POST)`). Then have the form submit to the same page (`action=""`)

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Thank you!